# how do you check your gemfile.lock into version control?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04, vps, linode

When deploying my Rails App to Linode via Capistrano/Unicorn, when running this command "bundle exec cap deploy:cold" it's giving the error :

```
    The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked your       Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.
command finished in 495ms
 *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

I've searched around and can't seem to find a solution. Any one know any solutions? How do you check your gemfile.lock into version control

https://github.com/Ruekompa/itcinema.git

After a little while of running running countless commands and attempts, I now notice there is a folder called cached-copy residing in /home/USERNAME/apps/APPNAME, and it contains my app.

UPDATE:
I have fixed everything. I simply rebuilt ubuntu server on linode and started over. This time my deployment worked. Thanks everyone

Comment: check your project home for .gitignore file and remove/comment Gemfile.lock

Comment: @adcosta - Yea I have checked that. That line does not exist. However it does have /gems in the .gitignore. I'm assuming thats okay. it would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed everything. I simply rebuilt ubuntu server on linode and started over. This time my deployment worked. I changed Ubuntu 12.04 to 10.04. Perhaps it was something in my capistrano recipes, for I was piggy backing off of someone else's code that was using 10.04.

Comment: Cool.  Don't forget to mark this question as answered since you answered it yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Gemfile.lock to your repository?

you can add it by

```
# in your app root dir
git add Gemfile.lock
git commit -m "Added Gemfile.lock to repository"
```

Comment: Yes @lichtamberg I added everything. Tried to commit file individually, but shows everything up to date. Here is git https://github.com/Ruekompa/itcinema.git

Comment: Make sure `Gemfile.lock` isn't in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Yea @jim I have checked that. file is not listed in .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Did you run the following command?

```
bundle install --deployment
```

Comment: Should I try that in production or development machine?

Comment: Well I guess it would have to be on my machine, right? Because there is nothing to bundle on my production server. I read somewhere not to do that on your development machine. Something about gems being stored in vendor-cache and having to check your Gemfile.lock everytime you deploy. Which oddly enough sounds like my error. But I don't know what it means. I've exercised so many methods. I read somewhere about files being in the releases folder in the VPS, and to delete them. People said it cleared that Gemfile.lock error. But my releases folder is empty. So I am so lost. haha.

Comment: Okay well I ran bundle install --deployment and it did install a lot gems. So I retried and received the same error.

Comment: After that did you have a Gemfile.lock file?  Did you also then git add and commit it? And push it to your production machine?

Comment: @michael I have a had the Gemlock.file. Should I have deleted the original? I tried to git add and commit, but it said everything was up to date. And I now notice there is a folder called cached-copy residing in /home/USERNAME/apps/APPNAME, and it contains my app.

Comment: that last part was unrelated. Just something I had noticed

Comment: Please be exact.  Do you have the Gemfile.lock in home/USERNAME/apps/APPNAME  Also, if you cd into that directory and do `git status` what do you see?

Comment: Wait, your app is in cached-copy?  Never heard of that.  I would go the the apps directory and just create the app there.

Comment: Ok its in deployer@li52-248:~/home/deployer/apps/itcinema/shared/cached-copy$ 
and the gemfile.lock is in there

Comment: do i just go in the apps directory and do like a rails new and do it by hand, is what you're suggesting?

Comment: - and when I cd into that dir, and do a git status, I get 'nothing to commit (working directory clean)